# django form field referencee from other model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that needs references from another model. here the example.

I have `models.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Inven(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sn = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='employee')
```

here my `views.py`

```
class InventoryListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'inventorys'
    model = models.Inventory
```

and here my `inven` `template_form.html`

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_name">
<input type="text" name="sn" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_sn">
<select>
{% for employee in employees %}
    <option value="{{employee.pk}}">{{employee.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

how to make employee field as a select list from `employee` model?...

Comment: do you get `employees` object_list in the template?

Comment: nope,  should `{% for employee in employees %}` change to `{% for employee in inventory.employee %}` ?...

Comment: You should use a ModelForm, which would create that select list for you automatically.

Comment: there's no way without `modelForm`?

Comment: Ow! I thought you had the obejct_list in templates. `ModelForm` is good for you as Daniel said. there's other ways, but you should consider the best --> [Django Model Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: if you want to use your own form, you can send all the `Employee` which in db through `context` and in template: use `select` tag as a wrapper and put all the `options` inside as you did above with `employees` loop

Comment: Of course there are other ways, but why wouldn't you use the correct way? Forms take care of output as well as validation; otherwise you'd have to write all that yourself.